# Applicacion React dentro de body

Tags: reactjs

Estaba haciendo una pagina en React, y mirando el codigo me puse a pensar porque que no se renderiza la app directamente en la etiqueta body de nuestro HTML, sino que en vez de eso lo hacemos en un div.

Answer (score 1):

Renderizar en el body puede tener como consecuencia colisiones con scripts que utilizan este elemento del DOM también y pueden producir errores difíciles de depurar.

- Referencia: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1568#issuecomment-280139884